# hover on an element with effect

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, transition

I created an effect on a list of images so that it enlarges when the mouse passes but when I go to this list the whole list performs the effect and not the selected image.
The current code performs the effect on all images instead of just one.
However, I select the element correctly

```
#homebrands {
    .brands {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        .brand{
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
            .figure {
                transition: transform 0.4s;
            }
        }
    }
    &:hover, &:focus {
        .brands{
            .brand{
                .figure{
                    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(0.01deg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the html?

Comment: You are sensing the hover on homebrands. I imagine you want to sense the hover on an image within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you're trying to add a transition to only objects in the `.figure` class. Right now, everything under `#homebrands` is affecting what happens to `#homebrands`. To fix this, remove the hovering from `#homebrands` to not affect it. Without your HTML, I can't tell what you want to change when hovered on, but this is what your code should look like assuming you want each `.brand` to enlarge when hovered.

```css
#homebrands {
    .brands {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        .brand{
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
            .figure {
                transition: transform 0.4s;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* This is moved: */
.brand { 
    &:hover, &:focus { 
        .figure { 
            transform: scale(1.4) rotate(0.01deg); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I adapted :)
.brand{
  &:hover, &:focus {
   .figure{
    transform: scale(1.4) rotate(0.01deg);
   }
  }
 }